# ActiveAdmin how to display values in dropdown but store keys to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

How can I display the string name, but save the integer key to the db in a dropdown in active admin?
I have this form:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Status" do
    f.input :status, as: :select, collection: App::STATUSES.keys
  end
  f.actions
end
```

which produces this and works fine:
[image]

but I need it to produce this:
[image]

This is the code which produces the above image. It displays the values that I want, but it doesn't save the keys (0, 1, 2, etc.) to the db

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Status" do
    f.input :status, as: :select, collection: App::STATUSES.values
  end
  f.actions
end
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Status" do
    f.input :status, as: :select, collection: App::STATUSES.values, :label_method => :status_name
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Here is my model:

```
IN_PROGRESS = 0 #default
SUBMITTED = 1
REVIEW = 2
PENDING = 3
APPROVED = 4
LIVE = 5


STATUSES = {
  IN_PROGRESS => 'in progress',
  SUBMITTED => 'submitted',
  REVIEW => 'review',
  PENDING => 'pending',
  APPROVED => 'approved',
  LIVE => 'live'
}

def status_name
  STATUSES[status].to_s
end
```

The status_name method works fine throughout my app, it just doesn't get called for some reason when displaying the dropdown.

Comment: You have extra `,` here: `f.input :status, as: :select, collection: App::STATUSES.values, , :label_method => :status_name`

Comment: that was just a typo sorry. It still doesn't work after I remove extra comma

Comment: Use https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum and clean up your model.

Comment: If I wanted, I could just use enums provided in Rails http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: I know, but simple enum is better.  But almost anything is better than mucking up your model (and, worse, the App namespace) with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use your hash as collection (or inverted hash)

```
 f.input :status, as: :select, collection: App::STATUSES.invert, :label_method => :status_name
```